# JQuery Mobile: focused input text doesn't respect z-index, appearing above everything else

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, z-index, android

I have a Phonegap application for Android with jQuery Mobile.
On an HTC Desire, if an input box is focused, it always go to the front, no matter which elements has above.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a known issue with android. Checking with the platform developers site is a great way to find out if what your experiencing is a bug or not. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18370

Comment: Did you add similar to below code to remove flickering in your app?.ui-page {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}    Above code has side effects in Android .Please comment code and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to apply the css property -webkit-transform : translate3d(0,0,0); to your input field ?